# How to change adc sampling time in STM32 to 20 Hz

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

I want to change the sampling rate of my STM32F303RE to 20 Hz. Is this possible with a ADC clock with 8 MHz and without a HAL_Delay() function?

Comment: Sampling time (topic) and sampling rate (text) are different concepts. I assume you mean you want to sample something 20 times per second. What methods have you tried so far and why they were not suitable? Do you want to use timer interrupts or not? Do you want to use blocking method or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a timer to trigger the ADC. Then you can vary the sample time to your heart's content.

You really don't want to play around with the ADC clock rate - cranking it down low will adversely affect it's operation as it relies on capacitive charges. The datasheet will tell you how low the adc clock can be set and still perform adequately.